How to send SocketCAN broadcast manager cyclic messages synchronized to the system clock
I want to use the broadcast manager to send messages synchronized to the system clock.
e.g. Send 1 CAN frame 100ms after each second boundary.
Initially, it seems this can be done by configuring ival1 based on the current time. Calculate the first desired starting moment and send a single message at ival1.
After this, ival2 takes over at the desired rate.
However, the following spoils it:

STARTTIMER: Start the timer with the actual values of ival1, ival2 and count. Starting the timer leads simultaneously to emit a CAN frame.

Does anyone knows a workaround (using the broadcast manager) ?
